# Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Cells' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have this bug when i tried to put data to cell from textbox.

The debug Marks this line:

```
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 1) = vCustomerID
```

(CustomerID is a timestamp string i.e 050918190442 ("ddmmyyhhmmss"))

Here my code:

```
Private Sub CB_Save_Click()

'Get Customer SheetName
Dim vCustomersShName As String
vCustomersShName = GetShName("Tb_Customers")


Dim vCustomerID As String
vCustomerID = UF_NewCustomer.TB_CustomerID.Value

'Clear filter
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Range("A1").AutoFilter


'Sort By CustomerID Asc
Sheets(vCustomersShName).ListObjects("Customers").Sort.SortFields _
        .Add Key:=Range("Customers[Customer_ID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Sheets(vCustomersShName).ListObjects("Customers").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
End With

'Filtering By CustomerID
Sheets(vCustomersShName).ListObjects("Customers").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vCustomerID 'Column 1=CustomerID

'Verify if the first row contain CustomerID
Dim FirstRowCustomer As Integer ' First row after filtering
FirstRowCustomer = Sheets(vCustomersShName).AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Row

Dim ExistCustomerID As String
ExistCustomerID = Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(FirstRowCustomer, 1).Value

Dim RowSelect As Integer
If Len(ExistCustomerID) = 0 Then 'If FirstRow is empty = It's a new customer --> insert row
    Dim LastRowCustomer As Integer
    LastRowCustomer = Sheets(vCustomersShName).Range("Customers").Rows.Count + 1 ' +1 for the header
    RowSelect = LastRowCustomer + 1 'Insert to new row in Customers table
Else 'If FirstRow is not empty = It's a new customer --> Update row
    RowSelect = FirstRowCustomer
End If

'Fill data from TextBoxs to Customers table
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 1) = vCustomerID
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 2) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Shem.Value
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 3) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Mishpacha.Value
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 4) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_LName.Value
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 5) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_FName.Value
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 6) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Tel.Value
Sheets(vCustomersShName).Cells(RowSelect, 7) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Mail.Value

If Len(ExistCustomerID) = 0 Then 'Insert new row
    MsgBox UF_NewCustomer.TB_Shem.Value & " " & UF_NewCustomer.TB_Mishpacha.Value & " was ADDED successfully (:"

    Room.Lb_Customers.ListIndex = Room.Lb_Customers.ListCount - 1

Else                        'Update exist row
    MsgBox UF_NewCustomer.TB_Shem.Value & " " & UF_NewCustomer.TB_Mishpacha.Value & " was UPDATED successfully (:"
End If
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `RowSelect` when the error occurs?  You could step through using F8 or setup that line as a debug point.

Comment: 492 (LastRow+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing references to the "Sheets" with "Worksheets". Also, use a with block to reduce redundant code.

```
With Worksheets(vCustomersShName)
    .Cells(RowSelect, 1) = vCustomerID
    .Cells(RowSelect, 2) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Shem.Value
    .Cells(RowSelect, 3) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Mishpacha.Value
    .Cells(RowSelect, 4) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_LName.Value
    .Cells(RowSelect, 5) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_FName.Value
    .Cells(RowSelect, 6) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Tel.Value
    .Cells(RowSelect, 7) = UF_NewCustomer.TB_Mail.Value
End With
```

Comment: If that's the case, then maybe verify that RowSelect is not being passed a value < 1.

Comment: As I wrote above - No. 
RowSelect=492.